# git-push для отдельной директории

Tags: git, github, git-push

**Resourse:**

Структура проекта

```
.git
build/
fonts/
node_modules/
src/
.gitignore
gulpfile.js
package.json
package-lock.json
```

**файл** `.gitignore`
Это те файлы, которые мне не нужно отправлять в репо

```
node_modules/
.idea/
gulpfile.js
package.json
package-lock.json
src/
fonts/
.git/
```

**Summary:**
Когда произвожу `git push origin push` 
почему-то в  репозиторий появляются такая структура

```
build
fonts
src
.gitginore
```

**Question:**

*Как же сделать, чтобы отправить только папку **build**(только содержимое этой папки, а не саму папку)??*
Заранее приношу извинения... Я не особо силен в **`git`**

Comment: Лайк за хорошо структурированный вопрос

Comment: Как вариант, может заинитить новый гит внутри папки build?

Comment: @Алексей, ну а если проект очень большой, то  занова создать новый git init??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Система контроля версий не предназначена для того, чтобы оперировать файлы. Она нужна только для того, чтобы хранить их историю. Всё остальное должны выполнять другие утилиты.

Когда Вы делаете коммит, в репозиторий отправляется ровно та структура, которая сейчас есть рядом с `.git`-файлом, за исключением пустых папок (если в них нет `.gitkeep` и объектов из `.gitignore`). Поэтому Вы видите такую структуру.

Таким образом, Ваша задача распадается на 2 несколькими способами.

**Способ 1**:

- Перенести всё из `build` в основную репу
- Добавить в коммит только те файлы, которые Вам нужны
- Сделать коммит

**Способ 2**:

- Перенести всё из `build` в основную репу
- Добавить все файлы, которые Вам НЕ нужны в `.gitignore`
- Сделать коммит

**Способ 3**:

- Создать в `build` отдельный репозиторий
- Сделать коммит

Как переносить файлы, это дело Ваше. Я предлагаю использовать утилиту `make`, сделав соответствующее правило. В таком случае, это будет выглядеть более технологично.

Отдельно можно обсудить каждый из этих вариантов, но все они выглядят как костыли, поскольку пушить бинарные файлы в репу -- это плохо. Я бы сказал, что это антипаттерн. Бинарные файлы собираются под конкретную архитектуру. Кроме того, человек может легко собрать соответствующий файл сам или забрать из последнего релиза.

Comment: а почему тогда  node_modules/ не попадает в репо

Comment: @John так он же у Вас в `.gitignore`

Comment: Так src/ и fonts/ у него тоже в .gitignore, а они в репо попадают.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов скорее всего проблема в том, что ранее они уже были закомичены и теперь `git` их оставляет в репе. С чем связана эта особенность `git`, я не знаю. Натыкался на такую проблему несколько раз. Глубоко не исследовал. Если Вы их хотите удалить, то это нужно сделать во всей истории коммитов, я подозреваю, либо же руками выпилить из репы и сделать коммит без них. В данном случае `.gitignore` не помогает. Потом их можно добавить и записать в `.gitignore`. Тогда `git` их больше не подцепит.

Comment: @John у Вас получилось?

Comment: Только пришлось отдельно создавать  git init,  другого выбора не было. Благодарю за все!!

Comment: Вы можете поставить галочку правильного ответа ;)

Comment: Я поставил галочку)) только за Ваше  старание, но все равно суть всего вопроса не полностью раскрыта для меня

Comment: @John Что Вам непонятно? Давайте разберёмся.

Answer (score 0):

Отправить содержимое папки **build** текущей ветки в корень ветки **push** внешнего репозитория **origin**.

```
git subtree push --prefix build origin push
```

Comment: вы своим «ответом» внесёте ещё больше бардака в голову того, кто, подобно автору вопроса, не понимает, что такое vcs вообще и какими сущностями они манипулируют в частности.

Comment: Это скорее вы своим неуместным комментарием распространяете миф про «сложность» гита.